# ¿Cómo puedo mezclar los elementos de 2 diccionarios de diccionarios? Python

Tags: python

Intento unir las funciones de transición de 2 automatas, las cuales están representadas por 2 diccionarios de diccionarios

```
estados1 = ['A','B']  #Los estados del automata 1
estados2 = ['q1','q2','q3'] #Los estados del automata 2
estados_union = ['Aq1','Aq2','Aq3','Bq1','Bq2','Bq3'] #Los estados del autoata union
alfabeto = ['0','1'] #El alfabeto del automata union
```

## Las funciones de transicion del automata 1 y 2, respectivamente

Donde la llave del diccionario es una tupla con un estado y una entrada y su valor es el estado al que lleva.

```
tf1[('A', '0')] = 'A'
tf1[('A', '1')] = 'B'
tf1[('B', '0')] = 'A'
tf1[('B', '1')] = 'B'

tf2 = dict()
tf2[('q1', '0')] = 'q3'
tf2[('q1', '1')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q2', '0')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q2', '1')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q3', '0')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q3', '1')] = 'q1'
```

## Deseo obtener una funcion de transicion 3, de esta forma

```
tf3 = dict()
tf3[('Aq1', '0')] = 'Aq3'
tf3[('Aq1', '1')] = 'Bq2'
tf3[('Aq2', '0')] = 'Aq2'
tf3[('Aq2', '1')] = 'Aq2'
tf3[('Aq3', '0')] = 'Aq2'
tf3[('Aq3', '1')] = 'Aq2'
tf3[('Bq1', '0')] = 'Aq3'
tf3[('Bq1', '1')] = 'Bq2'
tf3[('Bq2', '0')] = 'Aq3'
tf3[('Bq2', '1')] = 'Bq2'
tf3[('Bq2', '0')] = 'Bq3'
tf3[('Bq3', '1')] = 'Bq2'
```

Es decir, deseo generar un diccionario donde su llave esté conformada por los elementos del automata_union y de cada entrada y su valor sea el resultado de la concatenacion del valor de los estados del automata 1 concatenado con el valor de los estados del automata 2, dada una entrada del alfabeto. 
Por ejemplo, para generar el valor de la funcion de transicion para el estado 'Aq1' con entrada 0, debo buscar el valor de ('A','0') en tf1, el cual es 'A', y buscar el valor de (q1,0) en tf2, el cual es 'q3'. Luego entonces concatenar estos valores ('Aq3') y asignarlo a la llave correpondiente. 
('Aq1',0) = 'Aq3'
Ojala me haya explicado bien

Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente codigo, pero no he logrado mi objetivo

```
for i in range(len(estados_union)):
    for j in range(len(alfabeto)):
        estado_asociado = tf1[estados1[i],alfabeto[j]] + tf2[estados2[i],alfabeto[j]]
        funcion_transicion_union[(estados_union[i],alfabeto[j])] = estado_asociado
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si me habré liado entre estado y estado... Pero segun explicas esto debe funcionar:

```
estados1 = ['A','B']  #Los estados del automata 1
estados2 = ['q1','q2','q3'] #Los estados del automata 2
estados_union = ['Aq1','Aq2','Aq3','Bq1','Bq2','Bq3'] #Los estados del autoata union
alfabeto = ['0','1'] #El alfabeto del automata union


tf1 = dict()
tf1[('A', '0')] = 'A'
tf1[('A', '1')] = 'B'
tf1[('B', '0')] = 'A'
tf1[('B', '1')] = 'B'

tf2 = dict()
tf2[('q1', '0')] = 'q3'
tf2[('q1', '1')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q2', '0')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q2', '1')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q3', '0')] = 'q2'
tf2[('q3', '1')] = 'q1'

tf3 = dict()

for estado1 in estados1:
    for estado2 in estados2:
        for entrada in alfabeto:
            tf3[(estado1 + estado2, entrada)]=tf1[estado1, entrada] + tf2[estado2, entrada]

#Esto solo es para imprimir el diccionario
for key, value in tf3.items():
    print('tf3['+str(key)+'] = ' + value)
```

La salida es(ordenandola):

```
tf3[('Aq1', '0')] = Aq3
tf3[('Aq1', '1')] = Bq2
tf3[('Aq2', '0')] = Aq2
tf3[('Aq2', '1')] = Bq2
tf3[('Aq3', '0')] = Aq2
tf3[('Aq3', '1')] = Bq1
tf3[('Bq1', '0')] = Aq3
tf3[('Bq1', '1')] = Bq2
tf3[('Bq2', '0')] = Aq2
tf3[('Bq2', '1')] = Bq2
tf3[('Bq3', '0')] = Aq2
tf3[('Bq3', '1')] = Bq1
```

También puedes generar el diccionario directamente usando list comprehensions, aunque queda menos 'pythonico':

```
tf3={(estado1 + estado2, entrada):str(tf1[estado1, entrada] + tf2[estado2, entrada])
        for estado1 in estados1
        for estado2 in estados2
        for entrada in alfabeto}
```

No se si es que me he liado o es que tu diccionario `tf3` no se corresponde con los resultados esperados consultando en `tf1` y `tf2`. Por ejemplo para `('Aq2', '1')` buscamos `('A', '1')` en `tf1` y obtenemos `'B'` pero en tu ejemplo de `tf3` la salida es `'Aq2'` y no `'Bq2'`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó. Si, habia errado en algunas partes al copiar tf3. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hay una función muy útil para estos casos, `product`, que realiza el producto cartesiano sobre un conjunto de iterables. Lo equivalente a anidar loops `for`.

```
from itertools import product

for e1, e2, a in product(estados1, estados2, alfabeto):
    tf3[e1+e2,a] = tf1[e1,a] + tf2[e2,a]
```

O, con dict comprehension:

```
tf3 = {(e1+e2,a):tf1[e1,a] + tf2[e2,a] for e1, e2, a in product(estados1, estados2, alfabeto)}
```